# Using jqGrid in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, webforms

I've implemented and used a pretty functional grid through this tutorial for MVC:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx

I was wondering how to migrate this to ASP.NET WebForms, for another project I want to use jqGrid on, but is written in WebForms instead of MVC.

I've found some examples but they're rather incomplete (require me to declare the columns in both js and codebehind, don't feature paging, no multi-filtering, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery and page methods in WebForms application are working well together. ( http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/using-jquery-ajax-and-page-methods-with-a-asp.net-webservice.aspx )
After glance on the article you pointed to, I think they will work too. Here are what I think you should do.

1. Including the article above I mentioned, read more on using jquery with page method.
2. you will be able to reuse most of html and javascripts and c# data structures for communicating with jquery from the article (of codeproject).
3. What you need to do is that basically, you have to make your page method act as a controller while aspx as views. And adjust other elements accordingly. One thing you have to remember is that page method should be static.

Comment: obslete link. please check