# Using jqGrid with Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` in my application ,I have a requirement where I need to show data in a `jqGrid`.The data should come from a `Users` table.This is my first time with `jqGrid`, can anybody help me out to start with `jqGrid` with `Web Forms`.Any examples or links would be much appreciated .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include in any application just an empty table element and empty div for the pager at the bottom of the grid

```html
<table id="grid" ></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Then you includes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: 'someURLfromYourProject', // 'xxx.svc', 'xxx.asmx', 'xxx.ashx' ...
        datatype: 'json',
        pager: '#pager',
        gridview: true,
        height: 'auto',
        //... other parameters
    });
});
</script>
```

which will modify at the runtime the empty table and div in the grid. The data fir the grid will be get from the URL specified by `url` option.

It's important to understand that you can very easy integrate WFC, ASMX web service or ASHX handler in **any** your existing application. You need just add new page (choose "Add new Item" context menu in the Solution Explorer of your ASP.NET project) to your existing project. In the way you will create the code which are more independent from the technology used mainly in your ASP.NET application. If you decide later to migrate the application to ASP.NET MVC you can even not change the WFC ASMX web service or ASHX handler part of the application.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8545518/315935) you will find some URLs with demo projects which you can download and play a little. You can move the most code from the ASP.NET MVC example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935)) to your WCF/ASMX/ASHX code.

Comment: thanks a lot , will try it and incase I have any issues , I will get back to you thanks

Comment: @freebird: You are welcome! The most important to understand that you need just include in your existing web application some new component which provide pure JSON (or XML) data which can be used by jqGrid. So you have choice between many technologies. If it doesn't matter for you which one to use I would recommend you to use WCF, because it's the best from the performance point of view and it gives you the most flexibility. For example you can add to WCF methods which provide binary data like Excel tables. In case of ASMX web services you can't do this.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the links below.

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Using-jqGrid-with-ASPNET-Web-Forms-e28093-Part-I.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1638413.aspx/1

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1774/jqgrid-and-aspnet-web-forms/

http://praveen1305.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/jqgrid-with-asp-net-web-forms.html

[Using jqGrid in ASP.NET WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034713/using-jqgrid-in-asp-net-webforms)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**JQGRID example:-**

Download all the script files needed from the link http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

**Design.aspx**
i have defined the script in the body section of the aspx page.

Iam using this grid only for search functionality, So i have disabled the edit and delete functionality

```
  <script src="../JQGridReq/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JQGridReq/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <link href="../JQGridReq/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../JQGridReq/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <link href="../JQGridReq/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
         <link href="../JQGridReq/themes/start/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

          <script type="text/javascript">           
        jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
            url: '../Handlers/JQGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['TableID', 'Region_ID', 'Region_Name', 'ActionDate', 'Field', 'OldValue', 'NewValue', 'TableName', 'Who','Comment'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'TableID', index: 'TableID', width: 50, stype: 'text' },
                        { name: 'Region_ID', index: 'Region_ID', width: 50, stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: false },
                        { name: 'Region_Name', index: 'Region_Name', width: 100, editable: false },
                        { name: 'ActionDate', index: 'ActionDate', width: 80, editable: false, formatter: "date" },
                        { name: 'Field', index: 'Field', width: 100, align: "right", editable: false },
                        { name: 'OldValue', index: 'OldValue', width: 100, align: "right", editable: false },
                        { name: 'NewValue', index: 'NewValue', width: 100, align: "right", editable: false },
                        { name: 'TableName', index: 'TableName', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: false },
                        { name: 'Who', index: 'Who', width: 110, sortable: true, editable: false },
                        { name: 'Comment', index: 'Comment', width: 110, sortable: true, editable: false }
                      ],
            rowNum: 20,
            mtype: 'GET',
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30,40,50],
            pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
            sortname: 'TableID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            caption: "",
            editurl: '../Handlers/JQGridHandler.ashx'
        });

        $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridDemoPager',
                   {
                       //edit: true,
                       //add: true,
                       //del: true,
                       search: true,
                       searchtext: "Search"
                       //addtext: "Add",
                       //edittext: "Edit",
                       //deltext:"Delete"
                   },
                   {   //EDIT
                       //                       height: 300,
                       //                       width: 400,
                       //                       top: 50,
                       //                       left: 100,
                       //                       dataheight: 280,
                       closeOnEscape: true,//Closes the popup on pressing escape key
                       reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                       drag: true,
                       afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                           if (response.responseText == "") {

                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');//Reloads the grid after edit
                               return [true, '']
                           }
                           else {
                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
                               return [false, response.responseText]//Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
                           }
                       },
                       //editData: {
                       //    EmpId: function () {
                       //        var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                       //        var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                       //        return value;
                       //    }
                       //}
                   },
                   {
                       closeAfterAdd: true,//Closes the add window after add
                       afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                           if (response.responseText == "") {

                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                               return [true, '']
                           }
                           else {
                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                               return [false, response.responseText]
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   {   //DELETE
                       closeOnEscape: true,
                       closeAfterDelete: true,
                       reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                       closeOnEscape: true,
                       drag: true,
                       afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                           if (response.responseText == "") {

                               $("#jQGridDemo").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
                               return [false, response.responseText]
                           }
                           else {
                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')
                               return [true, response.responseText]
                           }
                       },
                       //delData: {
                       //    EmpId: function () {
                       //        var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                       //        var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                       //        return value;
                       //    }
                       //}
                   },
                   {//SEARCH
                       closeOnEscape: true
                   }
            );


    </script>
```

I have created a generic handler by right clicking the project and add new item as Generic Handler and  named it as  JQGridHandler.ashx  and then placed it in a folder named Handlers for making the ajax calls.

**JqGridHandler.ashx.cs:-**

```
public class JQGridHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        History myHistory = new History();    

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try {                   
    List<HistoryDetails> myHistoryDetails = new List<HistoryDetails>();
            myHistoryDetails = myHistory.GetAllHistoryDetails();
            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();   
         context.Response.Write(jsonSerializer.Serialize(myHistoryDetails));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**History.aspx.cs:-**
Iam creating a generic class called HistoryDetails which has all the required properties . Iam then calling the business logic.GetallHistoryDetails() which gets the records from the database using stored procedure

```
 public List<HistoryDetails> GetAllHistoryDetails()
        {
            List<HistoryDetails> myHistoryDetails = new List<HistoryDetails>();
            try
            {
                myHistoryDetails = BusinessLogic.GetAllHistoryDetails(IdVal);                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return myHistoryDetails;
        }
```

**References:-**
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609442/Using-JqGrid-in-ASP-NET