# jquery pagination and column sorting for the dynamically created html table

Tags: jquery

I am new to this jquery, can any one help me in creating the pagination(jquery) and column sorting for the dynamically created html table which takes the values from the database using web service(vb.net).

Comment: Did you try google like jQuery grid ? There should be lots of links takes you like jQGrid, FlexiGrid, etc

Comment: Do you have a better link for this, or any sample code as i'm totally stuck.

Comment: JqGrid it has better implementations and uses. try with
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764709/jqgrid-not-loading-data

Answer (score 0):

Please check this existing question [Choosing a jQuery datagrid plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622716/choosing-a-jquery-datagrid-plugin)

I like using **[jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)** as it is very simple and have much features.

You can use some GenericHttpHandler or Page method here and send a data as JSON format.

Also check below links for jQGrid

[How to implement JQgrid in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544828/how-to-implement-jqgrid-in-asp-net)

[Using jqGrid with Asp.Net Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347386/using-jqgrid-with-asp-net-web-forms)

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: I think, JQGrid is the best. But I dont agree with you about its sipmle to use for new users :)

Comment: Until we learn nothing is simple :). from my opinion i really enjoyed a lot with jQGrid features and got good support for my issues. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:315935+[jqgrid]

Comment: Thnx guys for ur quick suggestions . :)actually i am looking for pagination samples which retrieves the data through web-service(which i already got it working), but i need to attach the pagination plugin to this dynamically created html table.